# /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory

Tags: boot, graphics, xorg, xinit

My Ubuntu 16.04 system boots to X.Org failsafe mode (`xinit` fails). I cannot find out why. The file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` contains the following:

```
/dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
```

PS: My system was working fine until I removed 2 kernel images which were not being used (`4.4.0-57` and `4.4.0-59`). I use `4.4.0-53`. The boot process ends with `reached target graphical failsafe runlevel fallback` and does not go further.

Comment: please don't edit your title to add [SOLVED]. Your question still shows up as unanswered until you put the answer in the answer section below and accept it (or get an upvote or it) (or someone else provides an answer that is upvoted or accepted). It would be awesome if you could [edit] to remove the answer from your question and post it below instead

Answer (score 9):

According to the questioner, user152037, reinstalling the drivers fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Comment: Reinstalling the drivers worked for me on debian as well.