# Stuck in tty1 ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tty

I am stuck in tty1 after just rebooting my laptop. I don't know what happen. My laptop was log out and I wanted to log in but the system seems to bug so I reboot and now I am stuck in tty1.

I have tried all answers gave on this site on others but I can't get out. I am not connected also. So I write this from my phone. 
I have also tried to boot from live usb but i can't from tty1. 
Edit from comment:

Checking /var/log/Xorg.0.log I have found these errors:

```
(EE) Open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section (EE) AIGLX reverting to software rendering.
```

Comment: Look at /var/log/Xorg.0.log for messages that are tagged with "(EE)" for error.  Those messages will often explain why Xorg crashed which is a typical reason for not having a working GUI.

Comment: Checking /var/log/Xorg.0.log I have found these errors: (EE) Open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section  (EE) AIGLX reverting to software rendering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998628/dev-dri-card0-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: It's not clear - does it work from live USB, and/or from an alternate OS?

Comment: The suggestion in the "/dev/dri/card0: No such file..." question page was to re-install some Xorg server packages. Did Anicet attempt that? It would require knowing enough about the graphics hardware to understand which Xorg server packages to use.

Comment: Tested all your solutions but no one works for me so as i was on an important job i copy on an external drive my files and reinstall ubuntu and it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F7</kbd> ?
On my pc when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> it exits `tty`.

Comment: Yes I have already try this option. Leave me without result. I still in tty1. BTW I have also tried startx and Istill in tty1

Comment: I had a similar issue when I was trying solus budgie but I removed it as  I couldn't find a solution. I hope that you find a solution.